# How Can I parse this Json object in android?

Tags: android, json, android-webservice

Hello friends i am new in android . and i am trying to execute json but i dont knw how to parse this json responce.. please help me

thanks in advance .

json responce :

{"0":{
"id":"24",
"booking_id":"08140001",
"user_id":"20140620015800-127001OxL72Vdk5j",
"order_id":"4884c1fc-2a82-11e4-a5bf-22000a989249",
"points":"340",
"want_to_say":"",
"reason":"Business",
"checkindate":"2014-10-30 00:00:00",
"checkoutdate":"2014-10-31 00:00:00",
"first_name":"milan",
"last_name":"patel",
"email":"milan@ncodetechnologies.com",
"phone":"1234567980",
"mobile":"1234567890",
"country":"IN",
"state":"Gujarat",
"address":"ahmedabad",
"city":"Ahmedabad",
"zip_code":"123456",
"payment":"0",
"ddate_time":"2014-08-23 06:59:27",
"credit_card_number":null,
"cvv":null,
"expiry_date":null,
"language_id":"1"
},
"1":{
"id":"24",
"booking_id":"08140001",
"user_id":"20140620015800-127001OxL72Vdk5j",
"order_id":"4884c1fc-2a82-11e4-a5bf-22000a989249",
"points":"340",
"want_to_say":"",
"reason":"Business",
"checkindate":"2014-10-30 00:00:00",
"checkoutdate":"2014-10-31 00:00:00",
"first_name":"milan",
"last_name":"patel",
"email":"milan@ncodetechnologies.com",
"phone":"1234567980",
"mobile":"1234567890",
"country":"IN",
"state":"Gujarat",
"address":"ahmedabad",
"city":"Ahmedabad",
"zip_code":"123456",
"payment":"0",
"ddate_time":"2014-08-23 06:59:27",
"credit_card_number":null,
"cvv":null,
"expiry_date":null,
"language_id":"1"
}}

Comment: Have you thought of doing a search? Here's the first hit that I find on Google for [parse json android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Also you can use third party libraries like GSON...

Comment: yes i try but i didnt get proper answer.

Comment: @JamesNewton in that case, you can vote to close the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using Google's GSON?

Here's the link to the project: https://github.com/google/gson

The downlaod page: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.3.1%7Cjar

And a sample code to parse your JSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourObject[] objects = gson.fromJson(jsonString, YourObject[].class);
```

`YourObject` should look something like this:

```
public class YourObject{
    int id;
    int booking_id;
    String user_id;
    ...
}
```

Just a heads-up: If any of the Json elements have a `null` or an empty value, even though they are primarily an `int` in your `YourObject` class, it is best to declare them as `String` to avoid `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for parsing data from webservcie to android

```
        public void getValues_From_Web(String categoryId) {
            // Create request
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            PropertyInfo pi3 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi3.setName("Webnameid");
            pi3.setValue(categoryId);
            pi3.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pi3);


            // Create envelope
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            // Set output SOAP object
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            // Create HTTP call object
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_BRANDS);

            try {
                // Invole web service
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_BRANDS, envelope);
                // Get the response
                SoapPrimitive response4 = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                //Converting string to Array list
                  List1= new ArrayList<String>();
                  List2= new ArrayList<String>();


                if ((response4.toString()).contains("{")) {

                    SoapObject rep = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(rep.getPropertyAsString(0)
                            .toString());
                    for (int i = 0; i < jr.length(); i++) 
                    {
                        JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);

                        Id= jb.getString("Id");
                        NameValues = jb.getString("NameValue");

                         List1.add(Id);
                         List2.add(NameValues);
                    }


                } else {
                    StatusoutPut = response4.toString();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: you are using ksoap web service ?,use this method inside your async task do inbackground

Comment: Id= jb.getString("Id"); instead of this line use your --user_id, Booking_id it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use gson(from google) library. 
Download lib from https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list?can=1.
Place the download zip file in your libs folder.

Now you have to make a class where you have to declare all the json tag which you have to parse from json into that class. For eg

```
Class objClass{

String id;

String booking_id;

String user_id;
...
...

String language_id;

}
```

Now you have to make a object of gson

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

Now, pass your json string in gson.fromJson method.

```
objClass parseResponse = gson.fromJson(yourJsonResponse , objClass.class);
```